# Как убрать CSS класс при клике не на кнопки и меню? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать код, когда при клике вне области навигации и `button` убирать класс CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый набросок:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef()
  const [hasClass, setHasClass] = useState(true)

  const handleClick = event => {
    if (event.target !== buttonRef.current) {
      setHasClass(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={hasClass ? "add-color" : ""}>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Навигация</button>
    </div>  
  )
}
```

---

```
.add-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Данный вариант удалит класс `.add-color` при клике, если он придется не на кнопку. Можно оттолкнуться от данного "базового" примера и реализовать нужную Вам логику.